# operator operand type mismatch

Tags: types, operators, sml, operands

I have this code snippet

```
fun decrement_to_zero r = if !r < 0
                          then r := 0
                          else while !r >= 0 do r := !r - 1
```

from this tutorial

https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/standard-ml/

But I get this error:

```
stdIn:1.2-33.9 Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]
  operator domain: int ref
  operand:         int
  in expression:
    decrement_to_zero 10
```

when I call it with

`- decrement_to_zero 10;`

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why?

If you inspect the function's type signature,

```
- decrement_to_zero;
> val it = fn : int ref -> unit
```

you can confirm that its input type does not align with `10 : int`. But if you create an `int ref`,

```
- val foo = ref 10;
> val foo = ref 10 : int ref
```

and pass this to your function,

```
- decrement_to_zero foo;
> val it = () : unit
```

you will see that the reference has been updated, but not to zero,

```
- foo;
> val it = ref ~1 : int ref
```

So the function's name was quite poorly chosen, and written. It seems that a lot has gone wrong with that tutorial since I initially wrote it.

Although Standard ML has support for references, it is often more idiomatic to write pure functions. A pure function takes only values as input and returns values as output, but does not affect the world outside of the function (such as what the reference `foo` points to at any given point in time). So for example,

```
fun actually_decrement_to_zero n =
    if n > 0 then actually_decrement_to_zero (n-1) else n
```

And using this,

```
- actually_decrement_to_zero 10;
> val it = 0 : int
```

As you can see, the result comes right out of the function, rather than indirectly through a reference.

Comment: Despite the bug with that function it still seems like a nice little tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! I've learned a great deal of programming from short tutorials like those. I left out references as a deliberate choice, because I thought it would teach people functional programming the right way, but I realize now that it's better to teach a bad feature by a good example, than by a bad one. ;-)